# Can't get curl to do anything with github api

Tags: api, curl, github

So this is a really stupid problem, I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960

but it just doesn't DO anything when I type:

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/caspyin
```

No error (if curl isn't in the directory i'm in, I do get an error) but it doesn't noticably return anything.

```
curl https://api.github.com/zen
```

Also doesn't return the little zen saying.

These apis work fine in the browser but I want to be able to run more complex post scripts so I can create issues... and I'm just struggling to get started here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Do you get anything when you do `curl https://www.google.com`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have no reason to believe I'm behind a proxy (amibehindaproxy.com says no) but your suggested code does nothing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that they've changed and now require authentication in almost every instance. I solved this problem by requesting a private github key to use for authentication purposes and then played with the headers until I got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
curl https://api.github.com/zen -k --proxy https://your_proxy_host:443 --proxy-user your_username:your_password
```

Comment: To my knowledge I'm not using a proxy

Comment: I was able to get this to work behind my proxy... can you set the verbose option (-v or --verbose) on the curl command and let me know what you're seeing?